# JSON format to HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

I have a piece of code that reads SQL data and converts it into a JSON format

```
$sql = "SELECT students.studentnumber, students.firstname, students.lastname, badge_id FROM students
  INNER JOIN student_has_badge
WHERE student_has_badge.badge_id = 10
  AND student.studentnumber = student_has_badge.studentnumber
ORDER BY lastname ASC
LIMIT 50;";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//creating an array
$emparray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $emparray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($emparray);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

The output I get from this looks like this:

```
[{"studentnumber":"11111","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"},
{"studentnumber":"1","firstname":"Nick","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"},
{"studentnumber":"500740442","firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Baker","badge_id":"10"},
{"studentnumber":"00000","firstname":"Tim","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"}]
```

Now I want to put this data in a HTML table, I've tried various methods, but non of them has worked, can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Please explain why you don't just modify your `while` loop and make it generate HTML table, instead of generating an array you then convert to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$emparray ='[{"studentnumber":"11111","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"},{"studentnumber":"1","firstname":"Nick","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"},{"studentnumber":"500740442","firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Baker","badge_id":"10"},"studentnumber":"00000","firstname":"Tim","lastname":"Smith","badge_id":"10"}]';

$emparray = json_decode($emparray,1);
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>Student#<th>First name</th><th>lastname</th><th>badge id</th></tr>';
foreach($emparray as $key => $value){
     echo '<tr><td>'.$value['studentnumber'] . '</td><td>'.$value['firstname'] . '</td><td>'.$value['lastname'] . '</td><td>'.$value['badge_id'] .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: While the code appears correct, code-only answers are not very useful.  I find code with lots of comments (`// decode the JSON into an array so we can loop over it...`) to be far more useful.

Comment: @cale_b Ill take that into consideration on my next answer, Thank you.

Comment: Why not take it into consideration *on this answer*, and edit the answer to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution in PHP, then you don't need the JSON data, just create a table from the original array.

```php
<?php
echo '<table id="emparray"><tr>'
    .'<th class="studentnumber">Student Number</th>'
    .'<th class="firstname">First name</th>'
    .'<th class="lastname">Last name</th>'
    .'<th class="badge_id">Badge ID</th>'
    .'</tr>';
foreach ($emparray as $e) {
    echo '<tr><td class="studentnumber">'.$e['studentnumber'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="firstname">'.$e['firstname'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="lastname">'.$e['lastname'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="badge_id">'.$e['badge_id'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
I just tried this, but I just get plain text out of this, no table or what so ever

Comment: @Maarten - this code works properly.  You've missed something about how you've implemented it.

Comment: @Maarten maybe your SQL is not returning values. You seem to have left out the `ON` clause in your `INNER JOIN`. Also make sure you pasted the code INSIDE the PHP tags (if you're just seeing plain text, you might have pasted it in HTML mode by mistake).